# The idealizer of the space of vector fields with vanishing divergence

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

The space of smooth vector fields on a manifold is counted as a Lie algebra with the usual Lie bracket structure.

Is there a Riemannian manifold of dimension at least $2$ which satisfies either of the following conditions

1)The idealizer of the space of vector fields with vanishing divergence, properly contains this space

2)This space is an ideal in the space of all smooth vector fields

Comment: I lack deeper knowledge on this, but I remember reading somewhere that the diffeomorphism group is simple.  I don't know if this is sufficient to say that the Lie algebra of all smooth vector fields is simple, but I would not be extremely surprised.

Comment: What I wrote before is wrong:  Take all vector fields that vanish on a chosen open subset $U\subset M$.  This is an ideal, since the Lie bracket of any vector field with one of those will also vanish on the $U$.
My apologies.

Comment: @KlausNiederkrüger  Thank  you  very much for  your  attention to my  question  and  your  comment. So  you  actualy  answered  the  first  part of  my  following  question  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327214/alternative-lie-bracket-on-chi-inftym-where-m-is-a-riemannian-manifold

Comment: I  assume  you  mean the  orientation  preserving  diffeomorphisms  is  a  simple  group, yes?